# Convert C++ Code to Assembly for SPIM

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, assembly, spim

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my compiled assembly file working on SPIM.  Basically I want to write a c++ file, and then generate a .s file that I can open in SPIM without error.  This means that the assembly must be in MIPS32 ABI using MIPS I instructions (some MIPS II).  How do I do this?  Right now I'm using g++ but I'm having major errors when I try ot run the file in SPIM.  I'm working on MAC OSx 10.6.3 and I'm compiling remotely on a linux machine.  Is there a special compiler I can use that will make this easy for me?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that term really.  I'm compiling using "mipseb-linux-g++".  I'm doing it on a linux machine, MIPS 3k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the compiler -S option, it will generate the assembly code.  Then you will have to edit the code so that SPIM accepts it.

You'll also want `g++ -S -fno-delayed-branch` if you enable optimization like `-O1` or `-Og` for more readable code.   Usually SPIM is configured to simulate a MIPS without branch-delay slots, but gcc will assume that the instruction after a branch is run even if it's taken.  `-fno-delayed-branch` gets gcc to fill any branch-delay slots with `nop`.

Another useful option is `-fverbose-asm` to have gcc add comments with the C variable name of each operand.

You'll want to avoid using C++ libraries like `std::vector` that compile to a lot of extra code vs. local arrays, especially without optimization, unless you really need those features.

Comment: By the way, C++ requires a considerable run-time support from other libraries. Try that first with an ordinary C program.